# Using $ORIGIN to specify the interpreter in ELF binaries isn't working

Tags: linux, linker, elf

I'm using [patchelf](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf) to modify rpath and the interpreter for already compiled binaries. The calls to patchelf look something like this:

```
patchelf --set-interpreter "\$ORIGIN/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" --set-rpath "\$ORIGIN/lib" ./grep
```

These are being set correctly, as verified by running `readelf -l ./grep | grep interpreter`, which outputs:

```
[Requesting program interpreter: $ORIGIN/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

When I try to run the executable, however, I get the following error:

```
-bash: ./grep: No such file or directory
```

This seems to indicate that there's an issue with the linker. If I specify an absolute path instead of using `$ORIGIN` then it seems to work fine.

I'm wondering if there's something incorrect about how I'm using `$ORIGIN` here, or if this is perhaps something that has perhaps been disabled on a system level?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If I specify an absolute path instead of using $ORIGIN then it seems to work fine.

This is working as intended.

It is the dynamic linker that interprets (expands) `$ORIGIN` and other special tokens.

The Linux kernel *doesn't*.

And it is the kernel that reads `PT_INTERP` segment of the main executable and (if present) loads and invokes the interpreter (the dynamic linker). When you set interpreter to non-existant path (such as `$ORIGIN/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`), you get `ENOENT` from the kernel `execve` system call.

There is no way to make interpreter itself be anything other than valid path.

Depending on what you are *actually* trying to achieve, [rtldi](http://bitwagon.com/rtldi/rtldi.html) may be the answer.

Comment: What about this writeup of a security vulnerability using `$ORIGIN` in `PT_INTERP`: https://backtrace.io/blog/exploiting-elf-expansion-variables/ ? Is this maybe something that varies between different kernel builds?

Comment: @Ivanna That's specific to *Solaris* kernel. I updated the answer to reflect that the *Linux* kernel doesn't do that.